# what can we say about $f(x)= |\cos x| + |\sin x|$

Tags: calculus

If function $f:\mathbb R \to  [0,2]$ is defined by $f(x)= |\cos x| + |\sin x|$ then

1. $f$ is one one
2. $f$ is onto
3. $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$
4. The minimum value of $f$ is $1$.

I countered option 3 by fact that $f (x)$ is not differentiable at $x=\pi$ so it is not differentiable on $\mathbb R$.

I countered option 4 by inequality that $|\cos x|+|\sin x|\ge|\cos x +\sin x | \ge \sqrt{2}$ so min value is $\sqrt{2}$

I have doubt in deciding option 1 and 2. And also what is correct option
thanks. Btw book says answer is option 4

Comment: Note that if 4 is true, then 2 is false. Why?, also check $f(0)$

Comment: Careful with your inequality! $\cos 0 + \sin 0 = 1 + 0 = 1$

Comment: It can't be one-to-one if it's defined on all of $\mathbb R$ and periodic.

Comment: .. minimum is 1 (when abs sin is at minimum abs cos is max and other way round); it is not differentiable (recall properties of abs); not one-to-one (it is periodic with period $\pi/2$). I cant understand what is option 2?!

Comment: $|\cos(x)+sin(x)| \le \sqrt{2}$ and not greater than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since $\cos$ and $\sin$ are periodic with the same period, so is $f$, so $f$ being one to one is out of the question. It should be easy to see that $1$ is false.
- The second point is false because $f(x)$ cannot reach $0$ at any value of $x$.
- Your answer for 3 is correct.
- Your answer for $4$ is incorrect. Your inequality, $\cos x + \sin x \geq \sqrt 2$, is not true at all. For example, $\cos 0 + \sin 0 = 1 < \sqrt 2.$

Comment: For 4, I used |a+b|$\le $|a|+|b|. Isnn't it that way?

Comment: @singularity Yes, it is true that $|\cos x + \sin x| \leq |\cos x| + |\sin x|$ (this part follows from the triangular inequality). It is *not* true, however, that $\sqrt 2 \leq |\cos x + \sin x|$.

Comment: And cosx+sinx=$\sqrt{2}$ sin (x+$ \frac{\pi}{4}$)

Comment: You can see that 1 is the minimum value of f by : $(|\cos x|+|\sin x|)^2=1+|\sin 2x|\geq 1$

Comment: @Hamza That is true, but more or less irrelevant to the question...

Comment: @5xum: Far from being irrelevant, Hamza's hint tells us the minimum value of $f$ and hence answers question 4.

Answer (score 0):

1. false, because $f(0)=f(\pi)=1$
2. false. if exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|\cos(x)|+|\sin(x)|=0 $, then

$\cos(x)=\sin(x)=0 \Rightarrow \cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=0$. Absurd!

3. false.

$f'(0) = \displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t} = \displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}\frac{|\cos(t)|+|\sin(t)|-1}{t}$

But

$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{|\cos(t)|+|\sin(t)|-1}{t}= \displaystyle\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\cos(t)+\sin(t)-1}{t} \stackrel{L'h}{=} \displaystyle\lim_{t\to0^+}(-\sin(t)+\cos(t)) = 1$

$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0^-}\frac{|\cos(t)|+|\sin(t)|-1}{t}= \displaystyle\lim_{t\to0^-}\frac{\cos(t)-\sin(t)-1}{t} \stackrel{L'h}{=} \displaystyle\lim_{t\to0^-}(-\sin(t)-\cos(t)) = -1$

So, the limit does not exists.

4. true.

$f(0) = |\cos(0)|+|\sin(0)| = 1$ and

$f(x)^2 = \cos^2(x)+2|\sin(x)||\cos(x)|+\sin^2(x) = 1+|\sin(2x)| \ge 1$

Then $f(x)\ge 1, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ (remember that $f(x)\ge 0$)

Answer (score -1):

1. A function $f:a \to B$ is 1-1 iff $\forall a,b \in A$, $f(a)=f(b) \implies a=b$

But your function is periodic. You can easily provide a counter example by picking some value and then 'moving up' the number line by a full period and showing that $f(a)=f(b)$ but $a \not= b$

2. A function $f:A \to B$ is onto means that: $ \forall b \in B$ $ \exists  a \in A$ such that $f(a)=b$

There does not exist any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=o$. This proves 2 is false.

3. you're correct
4. consider f(0): |cos(0)| + |sin(0)| = |1| + |0| = 1 < $\sqrt2$